# How to access a class from a dynamically imported module

Tags: python, class, dynamic, import, module

I have dynamically imported a module:

```
module_object = importlib.import_module(audio_module)
```

Now if I get a list of attributes associated with that module:

```
print dir(module_object)
```

I get the following:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'aud_shell', 'shlex', 'sys']
```

I want to access the "aud_shell" class that is located within this module.  But since this module was dynamically imported, I do not have knowledge of what class it has within it.  How do I search within this imported module to get the class name and then access that class?

For example:

1. Dynamically import module
2. Obtain name of class within module
3. Access a method within that class

In the end I will have to do something like this:

```
module_object.aud_shell.some_method()
```

I hope I explained this correctly.  Let me know if I didn't make any sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually 5 minutes after posting this question I was able to solve it, but just in case someone else is trying to do the same thing here it is:

After you have imported your module dynamically:

```
module_object = importlib.import_module(audio_module)
```

You can obtain the class by doing the following:

```
module_class = inspect.getmembers(module_object, inspect.isclass)
```

Then you need to create an object of that class with the module.  This is done by:

```
class_object = getattr(module_object, module_class)
```

Now when I print the "class_object" I get the following:

```
>>>print class_object
audio_module.aud_shell
```

Now I just need to figure out how to get a list of methods within the class and access those methods...

Comment: You get a list of methods with [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), and access them with `getattr()` as you used above.

Comment: Hwat `getattr`does is not "create an object of that class with the module" - it simply retrieves the attribute of an object. A module's attributes are the functions and classes defined in it.  Also `inspect.getmembers` don't return you a single string that you can use in a getattr call - (the above code should not work) - it retirns a list of 2-tuples with a pair name/object. So, if you have a single class in a module `inspect.getmembers(module_object, inspect.isclass)[0][1]` is already that class, no need to call `getattr`.